# How to read data with many blank fields in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a tab-delimited file that looks like this:

```
"ID\tV1\tV2\tV3\tV4\tV5\n\t1\tA\t\t\t\t1\n\t2\tB\t\t\t\t2"
```

I use this code to read in the data:

```
df <- read.table("path/to/file",header=TRUE,fill=TRUE)
```

The result is this:

```
df
  id V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  A  1 NA NA NA
2  2  B  2 NA NA NA
```

But I expect this:

```
df
  id V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  A  NA NA NA 1
2  2  B  NA NA NA 2
```

I've tried `sep="\t"` and `na.strings=c(""," ",NULL)` but those don't help.

Comment: For me `read.table("file.txt",header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,sep="\t")` is giving the desired output (R version 3.6.1)

Comment: @Chelmy88 Same R version, but I get an error with `read.table(text = ss, header=TRUE, fill=TRUE, sep="\t")` where `ss` is OPs sample string. Odd.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Indeed if I also pass the text in a variable I get an error too, but not when reading from a file ?!?

Comment: It looks just having an extra `\t` at the beginning of every line except the header, so perhaps simply do `read.table(text=gsub("^\t", "", scan("input.txt", what = 'list', sep='\n')), header=T, fill=T, sep="\t")` ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't get it to work with `read.table`, so how about parsing the string the manual way

```
ss <- "ID\tV1\tV2\tV3\tV4\tV5\n\t1\tA\t\t\t\t1\n\t2\tB\t\t\t\t2"

library(tidyverse)

entries <- unlist(str_split(ss, "\t"))
ncol <- str_which(entries, "\n")[1]
entries %>%
    str_remove("\\n") %>%
    matrix(ncol = ncol, byrow = T, dimnames = list(NULL, .[1:ncol])) %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    slice(-1) %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate_all(parse_guess)
#  ID V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  1  A NA NA NA  1
#2  2  B NA NA NA  2
```

Explanation: We split the string on `"\t"`; the first occurrence of `"\n"` tells us how many columns we have. We then tidy up the entries by removing the line break characters `"\n"`, reshape as `matrix` and then as `data.frame`, fix the header, and let `readr::parse_guess` guess the data type of every column.

For good measure we can roll everything into a function

```
read.my.data <- function(s) {
    entries <- unlist(str_split(s, "\t"))
    ncol <- str_which(entries, "\n")[1]
    entries %>%
        str_remove("\\n") %>%
        matrix(ncol = ncol, byrow = T, dimnames = list(NULL, .[1:ncol])) %>%
        as.data.frame() %>%
        slice(-1) %>%
        mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
        mutate_all(parse_guess)
}
```

and confirm

```
read.my.data(ss)
#  ID V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  1  A NA NA NA  1
#2  2  B NA NA NA  2
```

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer. Ultimately, I achieved my desired result in three steps: 1) ignore the header 2) drop the first column (empty) 3) and replace the column names. Shell scripting to remove the leading blank space from the original (wonky) data has alleviated this issue. Thanks again, your function is food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

data.table's `fread()` had no problem reading in the string... but your data seems to have a `\t` too many (after each \n), which causes the creation of an extra column.

It is probably best practive to fix this in your export that creates your files.

If this is not possible, you can adjust `fread()`'s arguments to get the desired output.

Here we use `drop` do delete the first column that was created due to the the extra `\t`.
To get the right column-names back, we read the first line of the file again

```
string <- "ID\tV1\tV2\tV3\tV4\tV5\n\t1\tA\t\t\t\t1\n\t2\tB\t\t\t\t2"
data.table::fread( string, 
                   drop = 1, 
                   fill = TRUE, 
                   col.names = as.matrix( fread(string, nrows = 1, header = FALSE))[1,] )


   ID V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1:  1  A NA NA NA  1
2:  2  B NA NA NA  2
```

Comment: *"but your data seems to have a \t too many"* Well that's exactly the point/problem! Which causes `fread` to *not* reproduce OPs expected output.

Comment: @mauritsevers  but fread reads the data, you 'just' have to rename the columns

Comment: @MauritsEvers see updated answer to achieve desired output

Answer (score 1):

As Quar already mentioned in his/her comment, your file has an extra tab in the beginning of every line, so the number of column labels does not match the number of data fields:

```
> foo <- "ID\tV1\tV2\tV3\tV4\tV5\n\t1\tA\t\t\t\t1\n\t2\tB\t\t\t\t2"
> cat(foo, "\n")
ID      V1      V2      V3      V4      V5
        1       A                               1
        2       B                               2
```

That would be ok if the additional first column contained unique row names.
So there are two ways to address the problem: 1. remove the empty column (ideally by fixing the process that produced that file) or 2. fix the row name issue.

Here is my suggestion using the second option:

As the data is tab separated, I'd use `read.delim` which is just `read table` with reasonable defaults for this kind of file. Of course that throws an error when used w/o some tweaking ("duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed"). To fix that, we need to tell it to use automatic row numbering. That way you get almost exactly what you want:

```
> read.delim(text=foo, row.names=NULL)
  row.names ID V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1            1  A NA NA NA  1
2            2  B NA NA NA  2
```

All that's left to do is get rid of the row.names column. Alternatively, you may want the `ID` column to be turned into row.names:

```
> read.delim(text=foo, row.names='ID')
  row.names V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1            A NA NA NA  1
2            B NA NA NA  2
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: *"your file has an extra tab in the beginning of every line"* The issue here is to take exactly that into account. Saying *"the number of column labels does not match the number of data fields"* means that you're essentially ignoring the problem, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think so: by default, `read.delim` will expect k header fileds and k+1 columns after that and treat the first (unmatched) column as row.name. As the row names in this file are all empty, we get "duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed". By forcing row numbering, we got an automatic column name for the first column and the rest is parsed correctly. I'll edit my answer to better explain this.